# Android application plug-in architecture

Tags: android, plugins, android-ndk

I am experimenting with implementing plug-in architecture in Android, more specifically, cross-apk class loading

assume I have the following:
apk A and apk B, with the same `sharedUserId` defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`
*interface I* is defined in apk A, and apk B contains a *class IB* that implements *I*

I tried the following approaches

1. in apk A, use `createPackageContext` to obtain context of B, then call `Context.getClassLoader` and load the desired class name.  However, due to the fact that this creates two class loaders, and therefore I cannot cast the *class IB* loaded in B into *interface I*; which means I need to use reflection...
2. pass apk B to `DexClassLoader` (path to apk B obtained by `ApplicationInfo.sourceDir`) and failed with "**Class resolved by unexpected DEX**", probably because there is a duplicate interface I in apk B as well...
3. modify `build xml` and follow the approach in [Custom Class Loading in Dalvik](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html) to create a separate jar containing the *class IB* in B which implements *I* and put the jar into apk B's `assets` directory.  This approach looks promising, as I can load *class IB* and cast it to *I* without problems.  However, it creates the need for copying the jar, and I am not sure what will happen when NDK shared library is involved.

My question is, is there an approach that involves no modification of build.xml/ant.properties and works with NDK so library?

Comment: FYI, your class should be *B*, not *IB*. Capital letter I is usually (unless there's a good reason not to do it) reserved for interface names.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about other approaches, but for approach 2, you can exclude interface I when you were packing B to apk. Just exclude I.class file generated is enough.

You may find this post by Fred Chung helpful and may give you some hint. http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

Comment: Actually, my approach 3 is derived from that post (-:
As to exclude I.class for approach 2, that also means modifying build.xml, right?